# How to make background color extend all the way to bottom of page / content?

Tags: css, html, background

I am having a problem setting up the css properly

Here is my small code that I play with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        *          { margin: 0; padding:0; }
        html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #abc; }
        #container { background: #eee; width: 100%; height:100%;}
        #sidebar   { background: #a0f; width: 200px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; }
        #content   { background: #777; margin-left: 200px; width: auto; height: 100%; }
        #wrapper   { background: #357; height: auto; padding: 10px;}

        #column1   { background: #0f0; width: 66%; float: left; }
        #column2   { background: #f00; width: 33%; float: right; }
        #text1     { background: white; width:80%; min-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;}
        #text2     { background: white; width:80%; min-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
        </div><!-- end sidebar -->
        <div id="content">    
            <div id="column1">
                <div id="text1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end column1 -->
            <div id="column2">
                <div id="text2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end column2 -->
        </div><!-- end content -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is supposed to be a page with fixed sidebar on left and fluid content area on the right. In short pages I want the background color of `#content` extend to the bottom of screen (this works). On long pages I want that background to extend to the end of page (this does not).

I've added colors to all elements to see what's going where, but eventually the `#content` background will be white with 0.9 transparency, and there will be a background image on `body`.

How to fix that?

Update: see working example here: http://jsbin.com/AXUmALU/1/edit?html,output  - just scroll the output up to see the break in colors.

Comment: Please make an example www.jsbin.com, woot woot!

Comment: Updated the post with a link to jsbin - clever tool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have [what you want here](http://jsbin.com/AXUmALU/2/edit?html,css,output). In the css I have added some selectors for a `clearfix` class, which is very common. It looks like this:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

And I added that class to the `#content` This css is from HTML5 Boilerplate, which you can google. I also changed

`#content   { height: 100%; }` to `#content { min-height: 100%; }`

so that the content can expand beyond the size of the screen if it needs to.

Comment: Woot woot!  glad to help   :)